# grep search pattern in multiple files and output to different files

Tags: sed, grep

I have a directory /foo/bar that contains many files, let's say `a.file`, `b.file`, `c.file` and so on.
I am using `grep` to search for `xyz` pattern inside every file in that directory, but I want to send the result in new files such as `a.new.file` if the line was found in `a.file`, `b.new.file` if the line was found in `b.file` and so on.

My attempt: 
`grep -ri "xyz" /foo/bar/*` works well on screen, every line from the result starts with the path to the file that contains the pattern. Is this path stored in a variable that i can use to create the new files?

Edit:

Content of `a.new.file` should be all lines that match `xyz` from `a.file`

Content of `b.new.file` should be all lines that match `xyz` from `b.file`
And so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for T in *.file
do
  grep -- xyz "$T" > "${T%.file}.new.file"
done
```